# Tiling image in WPF

Tags: wpf, image

I am working on a game engine and right now I am trying to get some of my images tiled rather than stretching.

1. For some reason, the image gets stretched and not tiled. This is my code:

   ```
           string filename = "mario_right.png";
           BitmapImage bim = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Assets/img/" + filename));

           ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
           imgBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile; //this is what makes the image tiled.
                                              //You can change the imgBrush to some other modes as well.
           imgBrush.ImageSource = bim;
           player.rect.Fill = imgBrush;       //player is a Body (my own class), which inherits from the Rectangle class.
   ```

The actual .png file is 50*50 pixels. When I set the correct height and width of the player (50*50), the Fill image looks good. 
When I change the height to 250 pixels, I expect to get five Mario images on top of each other, but for some reason this doesn't happen - the .png just gets stretched.

(Stretching the .png for the player is just for testing; the code is actually for stone tiles in a Super Mario-like game.)

2. While testing, I have also tried to just insert a rectangle in the .xaml file and then filled it with the img. For some reason, I still can't get Tile to work! I have tried the four variants of Stretch, to no avail:

   ```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
       <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Width="50" Height="250">
           <Rectangle.Fill>
               <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/img/mario_right.png" TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None"/>
           </Rectangle.Fill>
       </Rectangle>
   ```

(Uniform, None etc give different results, but none of them tiles the image.    )

3.
Finally, I tried doing the same thing with the Grid background. Once again, the image only appears one, stretching so instead of 50*50 pixels, it fills up the entire window.

I start to think that the problem has to do with the setup of the MainWindow.xaml file, but if so, how can I scale the window (i.e. have it maximized) and render the image accordingly?

Thanks!

Petter

Comment: Read the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/tilebrush-overview).

Answer (score 1):

For tiling your image, you have to define the size (in pixel) that you want to tile. The properties that you need are `ViewportUnits` and `Viewport` (take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewportunits(v=vs.110).aspx))

So your code should be

```
ImageBrush imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
imgBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
imgBrush.ImageSource = bim;
imgBrush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
imgBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
```

I hope it can help you.